# Umbraco - can't login as admin after fresh installation

Tags: umbraco

I recently installed Umbraco CMS for one test site. I provided all necessary configurations and solved one error in Web.config file (added `<trust level="Full" />` to avoid Security issues). But when I try to logIn as administrator I got blank page or just refreshed login page that says - Session timed out.

In the database I checked existence of my admin account and found that is present and userType is 1 (which is admin).

I'm using MSSQL server 2014.

Comment: Are there any javascript errors in the dev console?

Comment: 1. No url found for api name updateCheckApiBaseUrl

Comment: 2. No url found for api name secrionApiBaseUrl

Comment: 3. No url found for api name treeApplicationApiBaseUrl

Comment: 4.GET 401 (Unauthorised). And all in file: DependencyHandler.axd

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it might not have installed properly maybe? Download the version of Umbraco that you installed from the website, unzip it and do a compare with the folder you installed in using something like WinMerge to see if there are any files missing from your installation?